# LightMap in three.js always makes material darker

Tags: three.js

It turns out that adding a light map to a material always makes it darker. This holds even for totally white texture. Is there a way to avoid this? Is it possible to darken only pixels under grey or black areas of light map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the next release of three.js, lightmaps will behave differently, and will be purely additive -- just like another light source. They also have a `lightMapIntensity` parameter.

You can try experimenting now by using the three.js dev branch, r.72dev.

three.js r.72dev